# VideoJS error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video-streaming, video.js

I am playing Video's streaming by VideoJS in a popup or in some window.
Videos are playing perfectly good.
But while playing if i close the modal or window i got this error  on console.

```
video-js.js:2568 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null
    at validateTarget (video-js.js:2568)
    at normalizeListenArgs (video-js.js:2647)
    at Html5.one (video-js.js:2787)
    at Player.userActive (video-js.js:27096)
    at Player.<anonymous> (video-js.js:27206)
    at video-js.js:4640
```

Anyone who got the solution to remove this of this please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is related to `dispose()` function in videojs, because you are not specifying element/playerid when disposing videojs player:

```
for ex : videoJSPlayer = element

 if (videojs.getPlayer("videoJSPlayer")) {
     videojs("videoJSPlayer").dispose();
   }
```